# Render items from 2D Array in React Native JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I'd like to create a menu based on a 2 dimensional Array: title and icon name.

Here's what I tried:

```
class Menu2 extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { Items: [['Home','home'],['User','user'],['Messages','envelope'], ['Finances','wallet'], ['Meal','silverware-fork-knife']]}
 }

 render(){
   <View style={styles.menu}>
   {this.state.Items.map((Items,i) => {
     return(
       <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.menu_item,styles.menu_item]} onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate(Items[i][0]);}}>
       <FontAwesome name={Items[i][1]} size={40} color="#fff"/>
         <Text style={styles.menu_text}>{Items[i][0]}</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
     )
   })};
    </View>
 }
}

export default Menu2
```

**Error returned is "TypeError undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Items[i][1]')"**

> What I was expecting is that "i" would by the iteration 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 (looping 5 times in my case) of my array and so Items[i][0] = the title and Items[i][1] = the icon name.
>   But I couldn't make it work like I would have liked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `.map` incorrectly!

The [MDN documentation for `Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) shows how to use the callback for this

```
function callback(currentValue, index, array)
```

Your callback `this.state.Items.map((Items,i) =>` puts the **`currentValue`** into a variable named `Items`, but then you use `Items` as if it were the full array!

#### Solution

Try this instead:

```
   {this.state.Items.map((currentItem) => {
     return(
       <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.menu_item,styles.menu_item]} onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate(currentItem[0]);}}>
       <FontAwesome name={currentItem[1]} size={40} color="#fff"/>
         <Text style={styles.menu_text}>{currentItem[0]}</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
     )
   })};
```

Comment: Ok thanks it seems to work better now but I can't manage to import it somewhere else, for example on my home page I've `import Menu2 from './Menu'` then further in render() I call it: `<Menu2 navigation={this.props.navigation} />` it gets me _Invariant Violation: Menu2(...) Nothing was returned from render._

Comment: @sNNNk that's a different problem, it's because you have no `return` statement in your `render()` function. Add `return (` line at the top of the function, above `<View>`, then close the `)` at the end of the function. That should fix it.

Comment: It's better, but I've still an error "Text strings must be rendered within <Text> component." I can't find where is the error

Comment: @sNNNk Since the problem you initially posted about has been resolved, it might be better accept the answer here and post a new question. I don't necessarily know the answer to your new problem and  nobody else will be able to see it if it is posted here in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

It should be Items[0]

```
      <FontAwesome name={Items[1]} size={40} color="#fff"/>
         <Text style={styles.menu_text}>{Items[0]}</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
```

check this working codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-cache-gyuge

Comment: Ok thanks, wasnt using map correctly, it seems to work better now but I can't manage to import it somewhere else, for example on my home page I've `import Menu2 from './Menu'` then further in render() I call it: `<Menu2 navigation={this.props.navigation} />` it gets me _Invariant Violation: Menu2(...) Nothing was returned from render._